# How to get only year from kendo datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-datetimepicker

I want to get only year from kendo datepicker.

```
var defaultyear = $("#datepicker").val();
// 2/22/2015
```

I want '2015'. I do not want to change display format.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved :)

```
  var defaultyear=kendo.toString($("#datepicker").data("kendoDatePicker").value(), 'yyyy');
```

Answer (score 3):

The .value() of .data("kendoDatePicker") is a Date, so you can also use the JavaScript method .getFullYear().

```
var year = $("#datepicker").data("kendoDatePicker").value().getFullYear();
```

Note that .getMonth() returns the month index (zero-based), so January = .getMonth()+1.

```
var month = $("#datepicker").data("kendoDatePicker").value().getMonth() + 1;
```